# How do I increment a number that is located in another file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make my code increment a number by 1 every time someone goes to another file and in that file make that same number increment by 1 again, but I'm having difficulty doing so.

Code in *number.py*:

```
def number():
  number=0
  print(number)
```

Code in *other1.py*:

```
import number

ask = input("Do you want to load another file? ")

if ask == "yes":
  number
  print(number)

else:
  print("Okay")
```

And I'm not really getting an error. I'm just not getting the number that I wanted to see. I want to see 1, but instead I get

```
<module 'number' from '/home/runner/Idek/number.py'>
```

Comment: Why not keep all the code in one file? Anyways, the error is because you should be using `print(number.number())`

Comment: Yeah, I know I could easily do that. I'm just really lazy and I don't want to have to write 4 more lines of code, but that did work, thanks a lot!

Comment: Another question, @QWERTYL did fix one of my issues but I also cant make it add 1 whenever I try to change the code in other1.py to ```number+=1``` I get another error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    exec(open("other1.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'module' and 'int'```

Comment: Again, you'd need to use `number.number += 1`. But remember you made `number` a function, not an integer (the variable in the function isn't global).

Comment: I have a bunch to learn, anyways thanks again I appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad to help! Don't worry, you'll get to where you want to be soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
print(number.number())
```